Issue with module imports and exports: (TypeError: featureCore is not a function)
I have a node project with the following format:
structures/extendedClient.js

utils/feature.js

tests/feature.test.js

In extendedClient.js I have the following:
class extendedClient extends Client {
    constructor(props) {
   // constructor stuff
   }

   runFeature() {
       require("../util/feature")(this);
    }
   }

   module.exports = extendedClient;

In my feature.js I have the following:
module.exports = (client) => {
    /**
     *
     * @param {require("../structures/extendedClient")} client
     */
  function featureCore() {
  // stuff (requires client variable)
  }

  featureCore();
}

I tried calling featureCore() from another location but it wouldn't import properly so I temporarily put it here. However, now I can't reference the function in any unit tests (Jest).
my feature.test.js file:
const  { anotherFunction, featureCore } = require("./util/feature");


test('expect birthday core to be read', () => {
    expect(birthdayReminderCore().toBe(3))
})

My test suite is throwing "TypeError: featureCore is not a function".
I'm sure that I'm missing something glaringly obvious, was just hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

After some fiddling around, I found that the line function-like exports that were used in other places in my codebase weren't necessary and standardized my exports.
In extendedClient:
class extendedClient extends Client {
constructor(props) {
// constructor stuff

}
runFeature() {
   require("../util/feature");
   featureCore();
}

}
module.exports = extendedClient;

In feature.js:
/**
 *
 * @param {require("../structures/extendedClient")} client
 */
function featureCore(client) {
// stuff
}
module.exports = {
 featureCore
 }

Then I need to import or mock client in my tests. Hope this helps anyone else coming along!
